# How to find input_shape of Convolutional Neural Network if I am trying to fit the data from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a pandas dataframe X_train with 321 samples and 43 features. Also, there are 18 different classes in y_train.

[image]

I want to train a CNN over my data, but I am having trouble to give the input shape in case of pandas dataframe.

This is the first layer where I am having trouble.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation = 'relu', input_shape = ???))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
```

All the tutorials have used image and they are just passing in the height, width and channel as the parameter of input_shape.

Comment: Your data seems to be 1D, i.e.  each sample contains 43 features in a row. `Conv2D` is for `2D` data, e.g. images.

Comment: @QuangHoang You mean it is impossible to use CNN over a dataframe?

Comment: No, I’m not saying that. I’m saying it’s impossible to use `Conv2D` directly. There’s `Conv1D`, and there’s reshape of data.

Comment: @QuangHoang So could you guide me how I can use Conv1D for this case?

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(???)

Answer (score 0):

if your input is not array...you need to convert into it:

```
arr_train = np.array(x_train)
```

then you can see your input shape with this code :

```
arr_train.shape
```

Note:
if you need to raise input dimension you can use this :

```
arr_train=arr_train.reshape(arr_train.shape[0],arr_train.shape[1],1)
```

Comment: @ma_shamshiri Does it help ?